# iOS to Java Publisher and Subscriber

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, jboss

I have an iOS application that needs to publish/subscribe to a Java server (JBOSS). Users will be able to send messages to other users of the application that will be forwarded by the server.

I am now looking to use Pusher as the mediator when publishing and subscribing. My question is - does Pusher queue messages up? If one user sends a few messages to another user but they are offline, what would happen?

Comment: what message queue and protocol do you intend to use?